# RestSharp Timeout

Tags: timeout, restsharp

I have an issue with RestClient response is coming back as

> "StatusCode: 0, Content-Type: , Content-Length: )"
> with the ErrorMessage of
> "The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing."

- Is this a timeout on the url's end or my httpclient?
- Is request.timeout correct?

It might take 5+ minutes for this request even though it's only 170KB of data due to their end being poorly optimized.

```
var client = new RestClient(url);

RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.Get };

request.Timeout = 300000;

request.AddParameter("access_token", AccessToken);
request.AddParameter("start_date", StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
request.AddParameter("end_date", EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
request.AddParameter("offset", offset.ToString());

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
var responseWorkLoads = JObject.Parse(response.Content).SelectToken("worklogs");
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two timeouts that RestSharp allows you to set.

When you create a new instance of `RestClient`, you can specify the `HttpClient` timeout that will override the default 100 ms using `RestOptions`:

```
var client = new RestClient(new RestClientOptions { Timeout = 300000 });
```

As the wrapped `HttpClient` is instantiated and configured once per `RestClient` instance, setting the request timeout doesn't override that setting, otherwise the client won't be thread-safe.

The request timeout, on the other hand, overrides the client timeout if it is *less* than the client timeout. RestSharp creates a cancellation token source using the request timeout, so the request will be cancelled when the linked cancellation token cancels.

I believe that currently RestClient also doesn't set the failure reason properly when the client times out, only if the token gets cancelled. I will create an issue for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up switching it to an HttpClient with the option client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
 it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer worked for me too. This is how I modified the constructor to create the RestClient with the BaseUrl and the timeout.

I'm using RestSharp 110.2.0 and it looks like the field is now called MaxTimeOut.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions($"{BaseUrl}");
options.MaxTimeout = 300000;

RestClient restClient = new RestClient(options);
```